# text wrapping around <p> tags

Tags: magento-1.9, html

https://humveepart.com/full-restoration/

my  h3 tags are wrapping around the p tags and I can't find out what is causing this issue

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , its a css related question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is CSS related question and you should ask it in `stackoverflow` not in here.

You may want to change/add some of your css like this:

```
.nav p {
    font-weight: 900;
    height: 100px;
}

.nav {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width: 60%;
}

.article {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that here is not the best place for your doubt, but I will help you. You need to add 
"float:none":

```
.nav p {
font-weight: 900;
width: 430px;
height: 100px;
float: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

After going to the link I used this CSS to get the basics done.

```
h3 {
    float: none;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 19%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just one line solution for that try below

```
h3 {
   clear: both;
}
```